# Read multiple CSV files with header in only first file - Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 5 CSV files and the header is in only the first file. I want to read and create a dataframe using spark. My code below works, however, I lose 4 rows of data using this method because the header is set to true in the final read. If I set the header to false I get the 4 rows of data back but I also get the actual header from the first file as a row in my data .

Is there a more efficient way to do this so that the header doesn't show up as a row in my dataset?

```
header = spark.read \
  .format("csv") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .load("path/file-1") 

schema = header.schema 

df = spark.read \
  .format("csv") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .schema(schema) \
  .load("path")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way do to what you want. There is a workaround that looks like what you did though. You could read the first file to get the schema, read all the files **but** the first one with `option("header", "false")` and then union the first file and the rest.

In python, it would look like this:

```py
first_file = "path/file-1"
header = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true").csv(first_file) 
schema = header.schema 

# I use binaryFiles simply to get the list of the files in the folder
# Not that the files are not read.
# Any other mean to list files in a directory would do the trick as well.
all_files = files = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("path")\
  .map(lambda x : x[0]).collect()
all_files_but_first = [f for f in all_files if not f.endswith(first_file)]

df = spark.read.option("header", "false") \
  .schema(schema).csv(all_files_but_first)\
  .union(header)
```